# jquery-plugin, Select2 4.0.1, how to remove auto sorting in multiple options selection

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using jquery-plugin, Select2 v4.0.1. In my project, by default the plugin sorts the multiple options selection but I don't want the options to be sorted. Any one please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do this, and it works perfectly for me.

```
function disabledAutoSortSelect(id_select2) {
    $("#" + id_select2).off('select2:select');
    $("#" + id_select2).on("select2:select", function (evt) {
        let element = evt.params.data.element;
        let $element = $(element);

        $element.detach();
        $(this).append($element);
        $(this).trigger("change");
    })
}
```